# Boto required for this module - ec2_elb_lb

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

When I try to create a external LB using ansible I always get the following error -

> "validate_certs": true, "zones": null}, "module_name":
>   "ec2_elb_lb"}, "msg": "boto required for this module

...
Code for this is-

```
- name: Ensure load balancer exists
  ec2_elb_lb:        
     name: "{{ elb_name }}"
     security_group_names: "{{ elb_security_group_name }}"
     state: present
     region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
     subnets: "{{ elb_subnet_id }}"
     purge_subnets: "{{ elb_purge_subnets }}"
     cross_az_load_balancing: "{{ elb_cross_az_load_balancing }}"
     connection_draining_timeout: "{{ elb_connection_draining_timeout }}"
     listeners: "{{ elb_listeners }}"
     stickiness: "{{ elb_stickiness }}"
     health_check: "{{ elb_health_check }}"
     aws_secret_key: "{{ SECRET }}"
     scheme: external
     register: elb
```

Answer (score 1):

From the message, it look like you need to install the boto using the following command:

```
pip install boto
```

or

```
sudo pip install boto
```

And make sure that you run these tasks against your localhost like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks: 
    - name: Ensure load balancer exists
      ec2_elb_lb:        
         name: "{{ elb_name }}"
         security_group_names: "{{ elb_security_group_name }}"
         state: present
         region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
         subnets: "{{ elb_subnet_id }}"
         purge_subnets: "{{ elb_purge_subnets }}"
         cross_az_load_balancing: "{{ elb_cross_az_load_balancing }}"
         connection_draining_timeout: "{{ elb_connection_draining_timeout }}"
         listeners: "{{ elb_listeners }}"
         stickiness: "{{ elb_stickiness }}"
         health_check: "{{ elb_health_check }}"
         aws_secret_key: "{{ SECRET }}"
         scheme: external
         register: elb
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Have you installed boto on your local machine (not one of your servers)?  Did you install it with the correct version of Python (that is, if you run `/usr/bin/python` and `import boto`, does it succeed)?

Comment: add delegate_to: localhost to your task

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation

Comment: I actually changed the host to a "BASTION" instance and it worked. I think this could be something related to what smiller171 has mentioned. will try this out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

What you needed to do is specify your PYTHONPATH. I've had this problem and this fixed mine.

`export PYTHONPATH="/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages"`

For my pyenv build, I had to use:

`export PYTHONPATH=/home/username/.pyenv/versions/ansible/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

ec2_elb_lb requires boto not boto3 and you can install it with `pip install boto`

If you are trying to create an Application Load Balancer, use `elb_application_lb` instead of `ec2_elb_lb`.